# Understanding time complexity of fixed size k-clique

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, np, np-complete

Determine the time complexity of the problem (e.g. lower
or upper bound)
Input: Graph
Output: “yes” if the graph contains a Clique of size 100.
Output “no” otherwise.

Determine a lower time complexity bound on this problem

I think the time complexity is O(1) constant because the clique has fixed size

Also if anyone could help direct me to a good resource on determining time complexity for decision problems it would be much appreciated

Comment: But the graph might be big.

Comment: would it then be proportional to the size of the graph? would i denote this O(n) (if the input of graph changes constantly?) or if the graph is always say of size 10000000 would it still be constant size O(1)?

Comment: I'm no expert. Personally I felt that to discuss the running time of an algorithm one usually parameterize the problem's input.  In this case, the problem could be to test if there is a clique of size larger than K in a graph with N nodes and M edges.

Comment: @Als the naive algorithm's---check all 100-subsets of vertices---time would be proportional to {n choose 100} * {100 choose 2}, which is about O(n^100). Not exactly constant. :-) I have no idea about nontrivial lowers bounds for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues in your question that need to be addressed. My answer here is necessarily brief and informal. To really understand and appreciate computational complexity, you'll have to study the material. [Papadimitriou 's book on Computational Complexity](http://www.amazon.de/Computational-Complexity-Christos-H-Papadimitriou/dp/0201530821/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1463040639&sr=8-2&keywords=computational+complexity) is the standard book: [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach by Sanjeev Arora](http://www.amazon.de/Computational-Complexity-Approach-Sanjeev-Arora/dp/0521424267/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463040639&sr=8-1&keywords=computational%20complexity) might be a lighter read for getting started.

**Computitional complexity** is usually measured with respect to the size of the input. For the K-Clique problem ("Does the input graph contain a clique of size K?") in the worst case you'll have to look at the whole graph (or at least most of the graph) to determine that there is no such clique. This means that the runtime of your algorithm will probably depend on the size of the graph (usually measured as the number of nodes `n` in your graph). Informally, this implies that the computational complexity cannot be constant, since it dependes on the size of the input.

**A lower complexity bound** is an asymptotic lower bound, i.e., any algorithm solving the problem has to have at least that computational complexity. So `O(1)` is actually a formally correct answer, though it doesn't provide much value. A **tight lower bound** is the highest asymptotic bound that is still a lower bound.

The K-clique desicion problem is NP-hard and thus it is very unlikely that a polynomial-time algorithm for the problem exists. You can find more about good upper-bounds in [this post on cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7420/why-is-the-clique-problem-np-complete).

Answer (score 1):

For a constant k the complexity is actually polynomial with O(n^k).
Source: https://people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/combclique-ipl-g.pdf

Comment: this one should be in the comment section